# How to get context in service (not applicationContext)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-context

Is it possible to refer to the context in service, but not using application context?

I am trying to achive ability to show snackbar from service when something occurs. This should be done in MULTIPLE activities.
To do this i need context and then refer from it to get the view using this line:

```
View rootView = ((Activity)context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

I am doing this in my service:

```
class MyService : Service() {

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
//TODO do something useful

val view: View = (this.applicationContext as Activity).window.decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content)
Timber.d("some jobe done")
return Service.START_NOT_STICKY
  }

override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
//TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
   return null
 }
}
```

However i am getting an error when refer to application context an cast it to the Activty:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Is it possible to handle this properly (refering my use case)?

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to achive ability to show snackbar from service when something occurs.

That is not a good idea. For example, it does not address the scenario where you have no running activities.

> To do this i need context and then refer from it to get the view using this line:

No, you would need the `Activity` object, as you see by your cast.

> Is it possible to handle this properly (refering my use case)?

Not in the way that you are approaching the problem.

Your situation is: the service detects some event, and the service would like to let the user know about that event. There are two possibilities:

- You have an activity that is visible, and that activity can then let the user know about the event by some appropriate means (e.g., a snackbar)
- You do not have an activity that is visible, in which case the service could raise a notification, or perhaps just drop the event (if there is no need to let the user know about it if the user is not in the UI of the app)

A typical approach to this problem is to use some form of event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, or any number of RxJava-based event bus implementations):

- The service posts the event on the bus
- Each activity subscribes to the bus for events while it is visible, unsubscribing when it is no longer visible (e.g., via `onStart()`/`onStop()`)
- If the activity gets the event, it shows the snackbar (or whatever) to the user
- If the service determines that nothing picked up the event, it uses some fallback approach

This approach offers better separation of concerns, as the service should not care about the details of how your UI lets the user know about the event. It also cleanly handles the case where you do not have a visible activity to use for the snackbar.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/EventBus/GreenRobot3) demonstrates this approach with greenrobot's EventBus, and
[this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager) demonstrates this approach with `LocalBroadcastManager`.

There are other solutions that do not involve a true event bus, such as the service updating a repository, which updates UI components via reactive means (e.g., RxJava leading to `LiveData`). However, a service should not be attempting to directly manipulate the activity's UI, in part because there may not be an activity.

Comment: Yes, but the vision of seting subscription in all my activities is rather bad for me, i have plenty of them in my whole application. If i have this ability in my Service i would not care about implementing subscribtion in all of them and just show Snackbar when something occur wherever activity is there present (like with Toast it is working as it needs only Context to work)

Comment: @Konrad: "i have plenty of them in my whole application" -- use inheritance to minimize the code duplication.